# How to get patch files from multiple commits?

Tags: git, patch

For example, let's focus on the latest 4 *successive* commits. commit1 is the latest while commit4 the earliest:

```
commit1 HEAD
commit2
commit3
commit4
...
```

I want get patch file from commit1&2&3. I have tried the following two commands, but they generates different patch files:

git diff commit4 commit1 -- > file.patch
git format-patch -3 commit1 --stadout > file.patch

I want to know if the difference is crucial? Could I use any of them?

Answer (score 1):

`git diff` only shows changes to the content, but `git format-patch` includes commit messages as well, making it more appropriate for most scenarios involving exchanging patches with other people (for example, so that you can share them using `git send-email`, or they can apply them via `git am`).

Answer (score 0):

I want get patch file from commit1&2&3
==> you may use git format-patch commit1..commit3 --stdout > file.patch

Comment: This question was asked in 2015 and has already been answered, please refrain from bumping old questions unless you actually have something to add.